# error log after doing the PI Update

Tags: pi-4

After doing a raspberry Pi update i noticed some error in the log
anything i need to worry about ?

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2021-05-19 20:33:08 EDT, end at Wed 2021-05-19 21:17:07 EDT. --
May 19 20:33:08 raspberrypi kernel: CPU3: failed to come online
May 19 20:33:10 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
May 19 20:33:11 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
May 19 20:33:11 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Jan  4 2021 19:56:29 version 7.45.229 (617f1f5 CY) FWID 01-2dbd9d2e
May 19 20:33:14 raspberrypi adsbexchange-mlat[523]: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:30005, retry in 30 seconds.
May 19 20:33:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[433]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
May 19 20:33:15 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: error resolving pool 0.debian.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 19 20:33:16 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[565]: HostedRendezvous: Rendezvous lookup failed: Hosted Bootstrap error: Network failure: Error connecting: getaddrinfo:
May 19 20:33:16 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: error resolving pool 1.debian.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 19 20:33:17 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: error resolving pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 19 20:33:18 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: error resolving pool 3.debian.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 19 20:33:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Raspberry Pi bluetooth helper.
May 19 20:33:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[740]: Sap driver initialization failed.
May 19 20:33:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[740]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
May 19 20:33:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[740]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
May 19 20:33:20 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: bind(23) AF_INET6 fe80::60f1:e632:5631:2f5b%2#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
May 19 20:33:20 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: unable to create socket on eth0 (4) for fe80::60f1:e632:5631:2f5b%2#123
May 19 20:33:21 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[565]: HostedRendezvous: Rendezvous lookup failed: Hosted Bootstrap error: Network failure: Error connecting: getaddrinfo:
May 19 20:58:08 raspberrypi kernel: v3d fec00000.v3d: MMU error from client L2T (0) at 0x3bc1000
```

Comment: `CPU3: failed to come online` that doesn't look good!

Answer (score 3):

Let's go through the log:

```
May 19 20:33:08 raspberrypi kernel: CPU3: failed to come online
```

I've seen this with a firmware upgrade, but only on CPU1. This is worrying. The Pi will run, but with one CPU less. This is a problem, which may be resolved with a full upgrade and a reboot, but I have not seen a predictable solution.

```
May 19 20:33:10 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
May 19 20:33:11 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
May 19 20:33:11 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Jan  4 2021 19:56:29 version 7.45.229 (617f1f5 CY) FWID 01-2dbd9d2e
```

just some info.

```
May 19 20:33:14 raspberrypi adsbexchange-mlat[523]: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:30005, retry in 30 seconds.
```

You're running some flight-info program probably. That program was started before the network was initialized, and it will retry after 30 seconds.

```
May 19 20:33:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[433]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

Your WLAN interface did not initialize. The easiest way to get WIFI up and running is to set everyrthing, including the country etc. via `raspi-config`. If you want to just test wifi,

```
rfkill list all
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

will enable wifi until the next boot.

```
May 19 20:33:15 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: error resolving pool 0.debian.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 19 20:33:16 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[565]: HostedRendezvous: Rendezvous lookup failed: Hosted Bootstrap error: Network failure: Error connecting: getaddrinfo:
May 19 20:33:16 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: error resolving pool 1.debian.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 19 20:33:17 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: error resolving pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
May 19 20:33:18 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: error resolving pool 3.debian.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
```

This is all due to the network not being configured.

```
May 19 20:33:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Raspberry Pi bluetooth helper.
```

See bluetooth later.

```
May 19 20:33:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[740]: Sap driver initialization failed.
May 19 20:33:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[740]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

As far as I know, the Pi does not really use the sap-driver.  Live with this message, or edit `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`  and put `--noplugin=sap` on the `ExecStart` line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap
```

```
May 19 20:33:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[740]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

The rfkill also prevents bluetooth from functioning.

```
May 19 20:33:20 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: bind(23) AF_INET6 fe80::60f1:e632:5631:2f5b%2#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
May 19 20:33:20 raspberrypi ntpd[574]: unable to create socket on eth0 (4) for fe80::60f1:e632:5631:2f5b%2#123
```

Apparently, your `eth0` does not work either. Probably no cable?

```
May 19 20:33:21 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[565]: HostedRendezvous: Rendezvous lookup failed: Hosted Bootstrap error: Network failure: Error connecting: getaddrinfo:
May 19 20:58:08 raspberrypi kernel: v3d fec00000.v3d: MMU error from client L2T (0) at 0x3bc1000
```

Since you have no network, all network stuff fails too.

The CPU line is a problem, the rest is for you to decide.